# CSS3 Opacity Transition Issues

Tags: html, firefox, css, css-transitions

I've been working on a site which incorporates CSS3 transitions and I have run into a slight hitch.

Whenever I hover over an element which has it applied to, text in the prior div blurs and returns to normal once the transition is complete. It works fine in Chrome and Safari, but run's into issue with Firefox.

I've recreated the issue here: http://jsfiddle.net/fkbc6/

The transition is currently applied to the list-item, which obviously doesn't work. I've also tried applying it to the image, but with no avail.

Any help would be much appreciated, as I'm all out of ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/fkbc6/2/

The mistake was the CSS you were applying had transform of 0.5 negative degrees (what purpouse?) and Firefox was re rendering all the fonts in a weird way because the style (twice applied in the css btw) was at the top divs of the example

```
#wepartner {
    overflow:auto;
    margin:70px auto 70px auto;
    padding-top:80px;
    background:#F6F6F6;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.02);
    padding:80px 50px 50px 50px;
    -moz-transform:rotate(0.5deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(0.5deg);
    -o-transform:rotate(0.5deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(0.5deg);
    transform:rotate(0.5deg)
}
#wepartner .content {
    -moz-transform:rotate(-0.5deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(-0.5deg);
    -o-transform:rotate(-0.5deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(-0.5deg);
    transform:rotate(-0.5deg)
}
```

Once removed everything should work just fine

**EDIT:** Wow, in fact you were applying two rotations with the same value and different directions, be careful with Ctrl-C Ctrl-V :P

**EDIT 2:** May this link could help you http://petermolnar.eu/linux-tech-coding/ie8-css-filter-matrix-cleartype-font-bug-fix/

Comment: Hey David, cheers for your help. The positive rotation was applied to the parent div (#wepartner) solely for stylistic purposes. The negative rotation of its child div (.content), was to counteract the the jagged artifacts (that happened during the original rotation) and to set the text and images back to their original orientation. I see this resolves the issue, but is there anyway to keep the div's rotation without these issues?

Comment: When you apply CSS to an element you also apply it to its children.
I tried to apply 0deg to the .content transform because a negative one does not conteract but act just like you ask adding a negative rotation to a straight div. Also tried to put a none value to the transform but does not works either. More info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/transform

I just edited my answer adding a new link

http://petermolnar.eu/linux-tech-coding/ie8-css-filter-matrix-cleartype-font-bug-fix/

Comment: Thanks for the links David. Afraid I still can't get it to work. Even with a single transform added to the parent and nothing to the child, I still seems to get rendering issues during the hover. Is this likely a browser bug, or is there something in my CSS that could be causing it?

Comment: What issues do you have, in the link I provided to you works fine for me in FF latest version, what code are you actually using? Can you post an update?